# Can't establish connection between Microsoft SQL server and Google sheet

Tags: sql-server, google-apps-script, google-sheets, jdbc

I'm new to using Google Scripts and am trying to make a connection to a MS-SQL (Microsoft SQL server 2012) but i got error message "Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password."
I checked multiple times hostname, database name, username and password are valid one.
I'm able to connect MySQL database in app script but i'm not able to connect MS sql server, may i know need to change any things in MS sql server or any thing else.

In my script I have used the following function:

```
var Database_Host = "54.XX.1.XX";
var Database_Name = "XXXXXX";
var Database_username = "test";
var Database_password = "XXXXXXXX";
var Port_number = "1433";

function getConnection() 
{
var url = 'jdbc:sqlserver://'+Database_Host+':'+Port_number+'/'+Database_Name;
var con = Jdbc.getConnection(url, Database_username, Database_password);
Logger.log(con);
con.close();
}
```

Note: I tried

```
  - Turn off the firewall

  - Changed inbound rule to allow all IP address
```

Comment: That error suggests you are getting a connection to the instance. Have you checked the SQL Server logs for the true authentication error? If you don't understand that error, include it in your question.

Comment: Can you connect to that instance using SSMS and those same credentials? Is it the default instance or a named instance?

Comment: @SMor Yes, able to connect SSMS using same credentials [Same credentials working in Project DB operations]. Also, I'm using the Named Instance.

Comment: @Larnu Checked SQL Server logs but I didn't find any authentication error

Comment: Then either you aren't logging failed connection attempts on that host (I suggest you should be) or you aren't connecting to the right host.